# pcap ethertype not consistent with ip version

Tags: c++, linux, pcap, libpcap

I'm using pcap to capture ip (both v4 and v6) packets on my router. It works just fine but I've noticed that sometimes the `ethertype` of an ethernet frame (`LINKTYPE_ETHERNET`) or a linux cooked capture encapsulation (`LINKTYPE_LINUX_SLL`) does not correctly indicate the version of the ip packet they contain.

I was expecting that if I get a frame whose `ethertype` is `0x0800` (`ETHERTYPE_IP`) then it should contain an ipv4 packet with `version == 4` and if I get a frame whose `ethertype` is `0x86DD` (`ETHERTYPE_IPV6`) then it should contain an ipv6 packet with `version == 6`.

Most of the time the above is true but sometimes it's not. I would get a frame whose `ethertype` is `ETHERTYPE_IP` but somehow it contains an ipv6 packet or I get a frame whose `ethertype` is `ETHERTYPE_IPV6` but it contains an ipv4 packet.

I seem to have heard "ipv4 over ipv6" or "ipv6 over ipv4" but I don't know exactly how they work or if they apply to my problem, but otherwise I'm not sure what's causing this inconsistency.

**EDIT**
I think my actually question is whether such behavior is normal. If so should I simply ignore the `ethertype` field and just check the `version` field in the ip header to determine if it's ipv4 or ipv6.

Comment: What is the C++ relation to this?

Comment: StackOverflow is about helping people fix their existing programming code. Please read  https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ,    http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: @JakeFreeman It's coded in c++ I guess. I don't know if the pcap library performs the same for other languages.

Comment: @shellter I guess my underlying question is should I just ignore `ethertype` altogether and just check the version field in the ip header.

Answer (score 0):

According to my (limited) understanding, both IPv4 and IPv6 can appear after an IPv4 (0x800) Ethernet type (ethtype). This is related to transmitting IPv4 packets over IPv6. When the ethtype is 0x800 and the IP header is version 6, then the address in the IP header is an IPv4 address mapped to IPv6.

One example that shows this is Linux UDP receive code, which checks for [ethtype 0x800](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.15/source/net/ipv6/udp.c#L354) and then converts the source address to ipv4 using [ipv6_addr_set_v4mapped](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.15/source/net/ipv6/udp.c#L401)